# Delete a row from a table using and Id React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this table which is created using data from my back end

```
    <Table
                style={{ marginBottom: "100px" }}
                dataSource={students}
                columns={colums}
                rowKey="studentId"
                pagination={false}
              />
```

And its columns are made with this function

```
    const colums = [
        {
          title: "",
          Key: "avatar",
          render: (text, student) => (
            <Avatar size="large" style={{ backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
              {`${student.firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${student.lastName
                .charAt(0)
                .toUpperCase()}`}
            </Avatar>
          ),
        },
        {
          title: "studentId",
          dataIndex: "studentId",
          Key: "studentId",
        },
        {
          title: "firstName",
          dataIndex: "firstName",
          Key: "firstName",
        },

        {
          title: "lastName",
          dataIndex: "lastName",
          Key: "lastName",
        },
        {
          title: "email",
          dataIndex: "email",
          Key: "email",
        },

        {
          title: "Gender",
          dataIndex: "gender",
          Key: "gender",
        },
        {
          title:"",
          Key:"buttom",
          render:()=>(<Button onClick={()=>deleteStudent()}>hello</Button>)
         
        }
      ];
```

I added a button which calls the deleteStudent function and sends it to my Backend

```
export const deleteStudent= (studentId)=>

fetch(`http://localhost:1020/api/students/${studentId}`,{   
    method:'DELETE',
    headers:{
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
}).then(checkStatus);
```

but I don't know how to pass the studentId for the specific row

this is my initial state

```
 state = {
    students: [],
    isFetching: false,
    isAddStundetModalVisible: false,
  };
```

Comment: Which package you are using `Table`?

Comment: im trying to expand on a online course tha uses antd <Table/> the course does not add the delete button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use second params to get the `studentId` like this. This is the same when you render `avatar`. You can read more props in docs: https://ant.design/components/table/#Column

```
(value, record)=>(<Button onClick={()=>deleteStudent(record.studentId)}>hello</Button>
```

Comment: thx  this worked i how no idea how but it did

Answer (score 1):

Your render function has options that you can use. You have used it for the 1st column. Why don't you use the same idea for rendering delete button? Render has text and student. Just use the student object and get the id and pass it.